# Working with decorators

Tags: python, decorator

I would like to build differents functions where each of them must work with a file. I've implemented this with a decorator.

Please, Let me know if it can be more pythonic:

```
def open_file(func):
    def a_wrapper(filename,separator,*args):
        f = open(filename,'w')
        return func(f,separator,*args)
    return a_wrapper

@open_file
def write_multiple_items(file, sep, *args):
    file.write(sep.join(args))

@open_file
def write_one_item(file,sep,name):
    file.write(sep.join(name))

write_multiple_items('foo.txt','--',"Hello","World", "!!!!")
write_one_item('bar.txt','--',"Bye World !!!")
```

Shoud I close the file? how?

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to use a `with` statement if you know that you'll only want to use the file in your decorated function.  Also, `separator` is an implementation detail - I'd leave it out of the wrapper:

```
def open_file(func):
    def a_wrapper(filename, *args):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            return func(f, *args)
    return a_wrapper
```

Also, as @Platinum Azure has pointed out, it's always a good idea to use [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) for your decorator function - this will ensure that the wrapped function's metadata is present in the wrapper function (which can be useful when you want to be able to distinguish your wrapped functions programatically).

**EDIT:**

The reason you should move `separator` out of the wrapper function is because you may have other functions that only need to take a file object and don't need a separator. If you create a function like this:

```
def say_hello(fp):
    fp.write("Hello World!")
```

You *can't* use a version of the `open_file` decorator that also attempts to pass in `separator` to `say_hello` - trying it will get you a `TypeError` because you are trying to call a function that takes one argument (a file object) with two arguments - a file object and a separator.

Also, even if all your wrapped functions will take at least one additional argument it doesn't *have* to be a separator.  This would be a legal function to wrap even with your unedited decorator:

```
def laugh(fp, number_of_times):
    fp.write("Ha! " * number_of_times)
```

That's what I mean when I say that `separator` is an implementation detail.  Ideally, your code is also documentation.  If you will only use this wrapper to write out data divided by a separator then you should leave the separator argument in your wrapper as it helps document how the wrapper is supposed to be used.  Otherwise, the second argument is no more important than the 14th - and shouldn't be called out with its own parameter.

Comment: Why is better to use my separator out of the wrapper? Could yo give me an example? I'm newbie in Python!

Comment: For anyone who might be running an older version of Python and who is unable to use this answer, take a look at my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11589492/129655) and you can see an alternative using `try`/`finally`. The `with` statement is much simpler though!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `try`/`finally` in the wrapper function to ensure the file is closed, or the `with` statement if you are using a new enough version of Python.

```
from functools import wraps
def open_file(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def a_wrapper(filename, sep, *args):
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        try:
            return func(f, sep, *args)
        finally:
            f.close()
    return a_wrapper
```

Using `with`:

```
from functools import wraps
def open_file(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def a_wrapper(filename, sep, *args):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            return func(f, sep, *args)
    return a_wrapper
```

Comment: I agree about the separator being an implementation detail, too. Just too lazy to edit on my mobile after all the painstaking tweaks I've done so far :-)